# Can I safely ignore a seemly outdated error notification of Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

The Overview of Azure Function from Azure Portal keeps showing the Error `configuring services in an external startup class`. However, my HTTP-triggered API works normally and timer-triggered function works successfully using Functions -> Code/Test. Plus, the **Create time (UTC)** is about 3 hours ago, and **Hit count** is never more than 36.
[image]

Can I safely assume that this is an outdated error and ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [github link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/errors-diagnostics/diagnostic-events/azfd0005.md), If a call to either of the `Configure()` methods on the `FunctionsStartup` class throws an exception, it will cause the function app initialization to fail. The functions host will catch this exception, log the error, and retry initialization. This retry helps to recover from transient errors, but permanent errors may be logged many times as the host retries.

As per [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75991406/how-do-you-solve-azfd0005-azure-function-app-error), this is a transient issue on Portal's end and that's why your functions works fine.

As a workaround, you can try to create a new function app and publish your functions to it.

If your issue still persists, I would suggest to raise this concern with Microsoft support team.

Comment: Wow, that sounds reasonable, thanks. I'll set your answer as solution soon if my function app works fine these days.

Comment: It disappeared sometime.