# Azure function throws ExternalStartupException despite correct host.json

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm having getting the following error in my function overview:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExternalStartupException : Error building configuration in an external startup class. ---> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.HostInitializationException : Referenced bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle of version 1.8.1 does not meet the required minimum version of 2.6.1. Update your extension bundle reference in host.json
```

despite my host.json being :

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Any idea what's up ?

Comment: Try to add this in your host.json -{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "2.6.1"
  }
}

Comment: This is not recommanded per : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register

Comment: Apology for the previous response, Try adding - 2* version of Function extension like below- {
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
} any luck with this settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the error is not up-to-date.

In my case, the error was fixed but the portal still showed the error. You can clear the error by heading over to the storage account associated with your function app and clearing the table :

> "AzureFunctionsDiagnosticEventsDATEHERE"

Thx to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76232621/884123).